# Visiting Japan as US permanent resident

Tags: visas, japan, vietnamese-citizens

A friend of mine is planning a trip to Japan on short notice. He is not a US Citizen, but a permanent resident. Is there a Visa on Arrival or an easy way to get a visa that applies specifically to US permanent residents?

Comment: It looks like there will be a visa exemption for Vietnamese residents in the near future http://www.thanhniennews.com/travel/japan-plans-to-waive-visa-for-vietnamese-tourists-report-25374.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No**, Japan only cares about your country of citizenship, they will have to apply for a visa via the usual process.  The only thing a green card gets you is [the right to apply for a visa at a Japanese embassy/consulate in the USA](http://www.la.us.emb-japan.go.jp/e_web/e_m02_06_04.htm), and tourist visas are *usually* processed in 2-3 days.

Answer (score 8):

Japan offers short-stay visa exemptions for tourism.  The list of countries that are eligible for visa exemption can be found at [Exemption of Visa (Short-Term Stay)](http://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/short/novisa.html). The citizenship of the visitor is the only thing that is relevant for Japanese visa exemption (US permanent residency status has no bearing).

Comment: For countries not on that list, like Vietnam, I'm curious what the fastest process is to get a Visa. In my experience, it's the consulate, but 2-3 days may be too long. What about APEC card members?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how it works for APEC card members. That would be a different question I suspect.